# Can I run an application developed in NetBeansIDE 64 bits on a NetBeansIDE 32 bits?

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to run a project developed in a NetBeansIDE 64, installed in 32bit platform?

Comment: Is this a pure Java application (does it use any native code)? Does it have any external dependencies?

Comment: no. i haven't completed the application yet.

Comment: Why don't you try it first?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch- Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a pure Java application that uses no native code, and doesn't rely on any external libraries, processes or programs (as you said in your comment) - then the answer is yes; you can run a Java application in a 32-bit JRE (or 32-bit Netbeans) and/or a 64-bit JRE (or 64-bit Netbeans) on Windows, Mac, Linux and any other platform with a compatible Java run-time (where compatible is tied to the target class level by the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't use any libraries that care about whether it is 32 or 64 bit, than Netbeans won't have any issues with it. If  you are using libraries that are going to have a problem with the switch, than that is where your problem will come from, not netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agreed with Elliott, you can run any program that developed using Netbeans 64 into 32bit platform as long you are not using 64 bit library such as JDK/JRE.